# Can the expression "final solution" be used on the site?

Tags: discussion, edits

Recently I've received an interesting [edit of my answer<sub>10k required to see</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61299482/revisions). It changed *"What's the final solution?"* header to *"What's the ultimate solution?"*, because of the completely unintentional [connotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Solution) of my original phrasing.

Even if I was aware of the connotations of this particular wording, without the edit, I wouldn't have made the connection.

I don't want any part of my professional life to be connected with any political context. I hope it's the same for SO community, so let's check if everything is right in the above situation, from the perspective of different members:

- "final solution" is a reference to the bad context and should not be used
- edits of "final solution" wording is a reference to the bad context and should not be done

Comment: I would look at it this way: will the phrase "final solution" trigger negative reactions in some people? I suspect so... in which case it's worth avoiding where possible, and accepting the edit. It doesn't require a majority of people to read your post in a negative way to make it worth avoiding unintentional hurt, even of only a few people.

Comment: @JonSkeet But why accidental wording is a bigger risk for hurt than explicitly attaching this context to it with edit? Your position opens up a big space for provocators, because who knows what words they'll want to mark as a reference to be edited and "explained"

Comment: @astef: I suspect relatively few readers will go into the edit history - which is the only way they'd see the context that you don't want to be highlighted. How often do you bother to go into the edit history of an answer that you find?

Comment: We all come from different cultures/backgrounds. For some cultures/backgrounds seeing "final solution" won't trigger anything, but for some it will no matter which context. This edit is in no way an accusation - your choice of words wasn't deliberate, however knowing that many people will find it offending and trying to use the words anyway might not be the wisest thing to do.

Comment: *But why accidental wording is a bigger risk for hurt...* @astef Because without the edit, the original wording would still be in your post where anyone who comes across your post will see it. With the edit, you have to go into the edit history to see it and it's prefaced with an edit description saying, "I'm sure this was unintentional".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: But it's not about what wikipedia says - it's about how human beings react, potentially involuntarily. There are all kinds of things we might say that we could justify intellectually, but which can cause unnecessary hurt. Why not just avoid that hurt?

Comment: @JonSkeet So far I am only seeing people react to how *other hypothetical people* might react.

Comment: I once had a pet that was shot. References to guns and ammunition trigger some nasty memories. Mind editing "Bullet" out of CodeCaster's answer, @Yivi?

Comment: @yivi I'm honestly still failing to see how it was a reference to nazism in the first place. The context makes it very, very clear that it was not.

Comment: Removing them implies the author of the words ___did___ intend those words to be interpreted harmfully. Even with an edit message like that. You can't slap someone ad say _"Oh I didn't mean to hurt you!"_

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: It clearly wasn't an intentional reference. Instead, it was a phrase that could be reasonably expected to trigger a negative response in a number of people. Yes, hypothetically - but reasonably.

Comment: @Cerbrus: "Removing them implies the author of the words did intend those words to be interpreted harmfully." How does it imply that? That inference suggests that it's impossible for someone to use harmful words accidentally.

Comment: Because if that implication isn't there, there would be no reason to edit it.

Comment: @Cerbrus: That assumes that harm can only take place when it's intended, and I don't accept that assumption.

Comment: No, that assumes that harm can only take place if there's a _reasonable_ way something can be interpreted harmfully. Taking 2 words out of ___obvious___ context isn't reasonanble.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I reject that assumption too... because when humans read words, associations are made before we go through an interpretation process of deciding whether the intention was to cause harm. If the *only* reactions were purely intellectual ones after considering the whole context, I'd agree - but that's not the way people work.

Comment: Yea, some people forget to think after reading words...

Comment: (I won't reply any further as I believe we have fundamentally different viewpoints that are unlikely to be changed by further discussion.)

Comment: If such unwarranted censorship is enforced, someone will soon be running a bot to check all comment phrases against all Nazi speeches and books, and we will be unable to post anything.

Comment: @MartinJames For what it's worth, comments containing the text "Nazi" are usually already deleted, albeit for other reasons.

Comment: User Bob Stein asked someone [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194998/821374) to not use the word "animal" because that's what Hitler would have done.

Comment: I don't think the term is proscribed per se, but, as you can see, it bothers some people. I don't see a problem with using it when relevant and appropriate (as long as it's not being done deliberately, to bother people), nor do I see a problem with someone who was bothered by it editing it to something with the same denotation but a different connotation to make them feel better.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Every reference on that Wikipedia entry is either directly or indirectly related to the holocaust or another genocide. The sentence you mentioned was added recently by an anonymous user with only one other edit, and that edit was was related to the ethnic cleansing of Germans. That sentence had no links or citations so I removed it. For native English speakers, the phrase "final solution" will almost certainly make them think about the holocaust. Google those two words in English and you will not find any references to programming.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: There is no-one in the discussion on this question that is actually bothered by the words _"Final solution"_... So far, all I've seen here are hypotheticals and what-ifs. _"What if someone is uncomfortable <...>"_ You can't base policy on hypotheticals.

Comment: I can understand why someone would be offended by the phrase "final solution". I can understand someone using the phrase innocuously without realising the connotations. But I can't understand the people who seem to be offended by the _removal_ of the phrase "final solution". Someone considerately edited out a phrase with unintended connotations. How is that objectionable?

Comment: "I don't want any part of my professional life to be connected with any political context." Everything is political or more precisely anyone can affix any supposed political views to any content, and they might be right or wrong, but it still depends on each one sensibility how to read words of others. If you feel the risk of offending anyone the only probable solution is stop saying anything (and even so...). On another view of that, and kind of the opposite, see https://wiki.lesswrong.com/wiki/Crocker%27s_rules  But the world is clearly not going in that direction...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek My original phrase is "I don't want any part of my professional life to be connected with any political context as much as it is possible". Post was edited, it is no longer my words.

Comment: @Cerbrus - It's not hypothetical at all. Someone was bothered enough to make an edit to OP's answer. That's why we're here. I don't think it's unreasonable to assume that the editor was trying to make a sincere improvement rather than just trolling (a possibility I mentioned in my previous comment).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: No. The editor isn't bothered by those words. He made that edit in the name of the hypothetical reader that might be bothered.

Comment: I wonder why programmers would use the phrase ultimate or final solution anyway? How can anything be ever final in programming? I could always continue.

Comment: @Cerbrus - I don't get that impression from the edit reason. The editor seems understanding about it being unintentional, and they didn't include an angry rant, but they do seem uncomfortable with the phrase.

Comment: In case anyone's interested to see, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299269) is the OP's very similar answer on another question, with the contentious phrase in a giant headline.

Comment: @khelwood It probably wouldn't be years ago. The current climate is... sensitive to social justice issues. How is this social justice? This is a textbook scenario of being "inclusive".

Comment: @Trilarion https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Don't get it. What has final in C++ to do with the term final solution? Is a solution using X an "X solution"? My take on "final solution" is that it is some kind of definite answer. I don't really believe in definite answers in programming. So, even if final solution wouldn't have any connotation, I would doubt that it's the right choice anywhere.

Comment: @khelwood "... in a giant headline." The whole answer has such gigantic headlines. It's probably a matter of personal taste. I would make an edit and lower the size of the headlines to improve the post, but since it would also affect the term discussed here, I'll wait.

Comment: [Sigh] 'The final solution to this numerical analysis is returned when the difference in the result between two successive iterations is less than the precision parameter'.  There, I made one up.

Comment: "The solution to this numerical analysis can be regarded as sufficiently good when the difference in the result between two successive iterations is less than the precision parameter." Is at least equally good.

Comment: @Trilarion sure, both sound fine to me.  If someone wishes to take issue with technical documentation over non-technical issues, that is not my problem.  If SO enforces irrational and irrelevant filtering of such texts, that is work that I am unwilling to do for free.

Comment: ..in fact, it is work I am unwilling to do if paid, on the grounds that I cannot guarantee to generate any text that will not offend somebody.  I will not be beholden to self-proclaimed victims over a software spec, or any other such professional or volunteered technical/engineering documentation.

Comment: @MartinJames That boils down to "It's okay to do such edits, but don't go looking for it". It's basically what I would also support. Just wanted to comment that there is not very often need for a final solution in programming. Of course I stand corrected and look forward to see lots of examples in the future.

Comment: @JonSkeet There are limits to how accommodating we can reasonably be. Demanding we police our language to this degree is far beyond reasonable. No one has been actually harmed. A person having a minor negative reaction in no way warrants censoring. If someone is actually at risk of harm from encountering a phrase on the internet, they probably need to be under professional care that directs them to avoid the entire internet and all public gatherings because no one can (or even should) exert that level of control over people. The expectation you're establishing is completely beyond the pale.

Comment: @Trilarion 'I stand corrected and look forward to see lots of examples in the future', lol, I guess neither of us are holding our breath over that:)

Comment: @JonHeller I dare say that if you're reading a lengthy post about programming and that particular phrase immediately completely breaks your train of thought by bringing the Holocaust to mind, you're the one with the problem. Looking for Nazi boogeymen everywhere is just going to drive you insane.

Comment: @jpmc26 Perhaps we just have different thresholds for what deserves an edit. I think it's perfectly acceptable to edit a post to fix grammar, add clarity, or avoid a possibly distracting phrase. There are many combinations of individually innocent words that may unintentionally become distracting. I don't advocate banning all uses of those phrases or punishing people who innocently use them. But I don't consider it censoring to edit a post and replace a potentially problematic phrase with a less distracting phrase.

Comment: @JonHeller It's not a problematic phrase with even a modicum of context. Any reader can tell that. Anyone who tells you otherwise is insisting on injecting something they know isn't there. That is intellectual dishonesty, and in today's culture, it usually stems from an ideological dogma that teaches them to look for "problematic" things for the purpose of causing as much disruption as possible. We should not be spending our time looking for problems that don't exist.

Comment: @jpmc26 Some words and phrases can be distracting regardless of the context. I am not claiming I am offended or physically harmed; I am not lying to score ideological points; I am merely saying that whenever I see the phrase "final solution" I immediately think of the Holocaust, and I believe that many other people feel the same way. We should avoid that phrase to improve our writing.

Comment: edits like that [feel rather niggling](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6737/168)

Comment: @gnat Maybe we should do a final edit undoing the previous edit.

Comment: @Trilarion that sounds like the final solution.

Comment: @JonHeller so what if the phrase reminds users of that racial mass genocide?  It happened, it should be remembered, it should never be forgotten.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not trying to deny any genocides. I was only pointing out that the anonymous Wikipedia user that people are getting their information from looks suspicious.

Comment: @MartinJames Sure, it should never be forgotten, everyone should know about it, that is important. But it doesn't mean that other uses of the phrase are either forbidden or encouraged. Calling a solution final is usually not a good idea though, most things aren't final. Replacing final with ultimate does not improve anything. There is hardly a legitimate use for an ultimate or final solution that's not kind of hybris.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I'm not a fan of attributing meaning to words where it ***clearly*** wasn't intended to be anything *close* to that.

Sure, the edit isn't necessarily *bad*, it's just different words to say the same thing.
I wouldn't roll back the edit, but I also wouldn't advise making edits like these:

## Always assume good faith.

This goes as much for the editor as the reader.

I'm afraid that such edits just draw more attention to the negative interpretation of those words than just not bothering to edit it, would have done.

Comment: "I'm afraid that such edits just draw more attention to the negative interpretation of those words" - only if someone looks at the edit history, which I suspect is vanishingly rare. It *does* draw more attention to it for the author, which hopefully means they'll remember and avoid using those words in the future. Sounds like a win-win to me!

Comment: @Cerbrus: But where we spot the opportunity for people being hurt and have the ability to avoid that, I think it's entirely reasonable to do so.

Comment: @JonSkeet Up to a point. This is just my personal opinion, but I think people are "hurt" too damn easily, and often just to get attention. In this example, there's absolutely no way that that line could've referred to what happened in WO II. To even _consider_ that is a stretch.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Sure, up to a point - but for me, "editing a post" is definitely within that point. Suggesting a site-wide search and replace would be beyond that point, IMO - but I really think this edit is a positive contribution to the site.

Comment: My point is that _anything_ can be offensive or "hurtful" if you completely take a select few words out of context. If you have to add a message saying _"I'm sure this interpretation of those words isn't what you meant"_ to your edit, then don't waste time editing...

Comment: _"The Ultimate Solution is a 1973 alternate history novel by journalist and former Playboy interviewer Eric Norden, set in a world where the Axis forces won World War II and partitioned the world between them, and is noted for its particularly grim tone."_ First google search result.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Would you seriously suggest that as many people are likely to have a negative reaction to that wording as to the original wording? If not, then the edit made things better IMO, and I would *encourage* that sort of edit.

Comment: Yea, sure, I'm comparing a book to the holocaust. I'm the bad guy here. You're using criteria like _"will <...> trigger negative reactions in some people?"_. All I'm saying is: People should stop being offended for the sake of being offended. History is a fact. Deal with it. _"Sorry you didn't intend this"_ doesn't mean the edit doesn't imply you do intend that meaning. If it were on my post, I might as well roll back the edit with a message _"Don't be dumb, it's obvious I wasn't referring to the holocaust."_

Comment: @Cerbrus: I suspect we'll have to agree to disagree. My personal approach is definitely to avoid using words that others may find offensive where I'm aware of it, and to accept corrections as graciously as I can.

Comment: I don't think a term has to be offensive to avoid it, in this case I personally avoid the term simply because I don't want to create the association to the Holocaust, even at best this can be simply distracting. Maybe the association is stronger for me as I'm German, and the German equivalent is more obscure and would essentially always be an intentional reference to the Holocaust.

Comment: @MadScientist: Yea, you really can't compare that specific German term with those 2 English words which are contextually ___completely___ different, on SO.

Comment: If I happened to use a header, and was pointing out and providing a final bluff statement using "final solution", and somebody happened to propose an edit indicating that I was making a reference to a offensive political party.  I would reject the proposal, revert the change if it was approved, and immediately flag the behavior for a moderator to handle.  I would find it more offensive that, an edit was being made, and the implication I have anything to do with that offensive political statement but I value and choose my words very carefully in everything I submit to a Stack Exchange community

Comment: The edit is just clearly bad for non english speakers... ultimate is not the same as final in develop terms.

Comment: @Cerbrus those 2 English words are not only contextually different here on SO, they are an arbitrary choice of a translator for the actual German term. Any synonym to those 2 English words would be a valid translation too. So if we assume that “ultimate solution” is a valid synonym to “final solution” (I’m not discussing that), it would also be a valid translation of the German term we try to avoid. So it’s entirely pointless to edit a post, to replace those *English* terms by a synonym. It would be an entirely different thing in German though, where we can replace literal matches by synonyms.

Comment: _the opportunity for people being hurt_ Hm, that sounds rather telling to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet The road to hell is paved with good intentions. While avoiding terms that might offend others seems like noble thing to do, it can certainly backfire in the long run. Context is the king, and if we start dancing around words that might offend or hurt even when they are used completely out of context, soon enough we will run out of words. Different words have different meaning  and carry different connotations to different people. We simply cannot cater to all.

Answer (score 60):

Imho the whole topic (the edit and this question) are rised from nowhere.

> the term "final solution" refers to Hitler's policies

The context is important. Was it a post about history? No? Hitler was telling "Guten Morgen" every day, should those two words be removed from German language? No?

We are programmers and words such as "master/slave" are our professional *terms*. I refuse to take modern [nonsense](https://www.cnet.com/news/master-and-slave-tech-terms-face-scrutiny-amid-anti-racism-efforts/) into account in my daily work, "your words become your actions" is not truth, otherwise Call of Duty players would have killed all their schoolmates already.

There is a profession to correct public speeches of others. It exists because some people may decide to be insulted by someone's words.

SO is about programming. It's a programmers site, not about history, politics or modern movements. It's agnostic to your country past or future. We are talking about programming here, rest is offtopic. If public visitors (non programmers) come here, *they* have to adjust, nor we have to adjust our established terminology to make them happier.

When colleague say "Let's kill it", he doesn't talk about murdering peoples. When another programmer say "Final solution" he means *solution to the problem*, which happens to be *final*. He didn't mean that other thing of Hitler. Simply.

> Can the expression “final solution” be used on the site?

Yes of course. Slave, kill, blacklist, etc. are also good. I will understand you correctly and the other programmers here too.

If someone decide to edit it without it losing the meaning, just let him.

P.S.: it would be funny if "ultimate solution" will insult another group of people. It's so stupid to be unable to express obvious intent with certain words combination. How many of such exists? Should our kids learn them all?

Comment: It has already begun though... https://bugs.python.org/issue34605 ,  https://github.com/ContributorCovenant/contributor_covenant/issues/569

Comment: [SE's stance on black/whitelist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352702/241919)

Comment: @Gimby oh, those dumpster fire. Yeah...

Comment: There are over 3,000 questions that are selected by '`is:q "final solution"`' on Stack Overflow. There are over 7,000 answers that are selected by '`is:a "final solution"`'.  The OP's question is making a mountain out of a molehill, and there are many other mountains and even more other molehills that should be dealt with more urgently.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, this whole "words are violence" nonsense has its roots in postmodernism. People literally believe that words may cause them physical harm, and the only criteria of defining which words are violence is their own perception. This latter idea is called "standpoint epistemology".

Comment: I would disagree about the "Guten Morgen" part. The term "Endlösung" is gone from the German language, using it outside of Nazi documentaries will have people staring at you wondering what is wrong with you. It's like a swastika. Sure, there *are* other legitimate uses especially in other cultures, but generally speaking, running around with one is not a good idea, if you don't want to be mistaken for a Nazi. It's not "just a random word Hitler used". It's a very distinctive Nazi ideology  term.

Comment: @nvoigt, good point. This word is forbidden because of guilt the germans feel currently for their nazis past. It's cultural specific, local, let them be. What I don't understand is why "final solution" phrase, which happens to be just a translation of that bad german word, should be forbidden/censored? If german understand "final solution" as "Endlösung" and not as "finale Lösung" it's his personal problem.

Comment: Ah, so.. the translation "Final solution" is bad. Is "End solution" fine? How about `String final SOLUTION = "solution";` in code?

Comment: @AndrewT. With no small amount of irony, the phrase "ultimate solution" appears in the text of the SE stance on black/whitelisting. "Though removing and adjusting such offensive terminology is itself not an ultimate solution, [...]".

Comment: As a German, I have to disagree wholeheartedly. "Guten Morgen" is just a totally normal German phrase that is used every day. "Endlösung" ist never ever used in the German language anymore (except in documentaries about the Nazi regime and by far right wing extremists who dream of the Fourth Reich).

Answer (score 31):

One of the reasons why we have edits is so that the community can improve the post.

In this case, a member of the community improved the post by removing words that have an unfortunate connotation.

No one is saying that you should recognize that connotation, or anything else related to your behavior; rather they're doing their part to ensure the post gets the best look it possibly can.

That's entirely appropriate for an edit.

Comment: Did they improve the post though? its relatively probable that someone else could have negative connotations with the phrase "ultimate solution". For example, changing black list to blocklist; that could have negative connotations for people who sympathized with the hunger strikers that died in the H block prison. Should I edit block list to something other than blacklist and blocklist because I know both could have negative connotations. Where do you draw the line on edits like this? In software, final solution is a known, self explanitory term

Comment: My other problem with edits like this is  "ultimate solution" does not translate to "final solution". For people who speak English as a second language; final solution is a known term in the software world. Ultimate solution is less clear, to me at least and can lead to confusion. To me I would interpret the "ultimate solution" as looking for the most performant solution, which is different to how I would interpret someone looking for a final solution

Comment: @Kevin How is "final solution" a known software term? I googled "final solution software" and nothing but holocaust pages came up. Wikipedia does not know about it either: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Solution_(disambiguation)

Comment: @nvoigt From what I can tell everyone in this entire thread (with maybe the exception of yourself) knows exactly what final solution means. Does that alone not indicate it to be a known self explanitory term?

Comment: Even from a question quality perspective, the use of ultimate adds ambiguity that final does not. Ultimate can mean either final or most performant, in this use-case, both would make perfect sense. Like I said, I would interpret ultimate as most performant in a use-case like this, which is not What the question wanted. I don't think we should degrade question quality with changes like this.

Answer (score 15):

I think that especially your second bullet point makes this more of a philosophical question: you used the phrase innocently, and now thanks to that edit you feel it was made a political issue.

This causes you to wonder: is it a bad edit, because now you have negative feelings about the term, or is it a good edit, because people who knew about the term and might be negatively impacted, now don't have to read it anymore.

I'd tend to the latter.

Comment: Let's not talk about this in vague terms. What kind of "negative impact" are you actually talking about?

Comment: That statement applies to any term or phrase that could have offensive connotations.

Comment: Or the other way around: does it harm you in any way that that phrase was edited out? Do you feel your freedom of speech being eroded? What if someone posts _"Formatting your hard drive to get rid of a compiler error is like the Tiananmen Square of solutions"_?

Comment: The harm I perceive from the edit is the promotion of a critical race theory value system, and that is no small harm. Granted, that would not be the case if we weren't in the middle of that top down cultural pressure, but we objectively are (including or especially here on SO). The only "negative impact" I can see from leaving it in is a very small number of people feel a little bad for a few minutes and then move on with their day. Do you have some greater level of harm in mind?

Comment: @jpmc I don't follow your reasoning. You think the edit made it into a political issue, or that the text was not harmful in any way?

Comment: I explicitly told you the only "harm" I can reasonably imagine from the phrase as it was used, which is not actually harm of any kind. That's why I'm asking what kind of harm you expect will come of it. I think the edit comes from and promotes a mindset that is doing harm to my and SO's culture as we speak.

Comment: And I told you explicitly that I don't understand what you're talking about. So because you saw no problem in the phrase, there was no problem? That is indeed a harmful mindset. If that's not what you meant, would you explain it in more plain language to me?

Comment: If there's actual harm that would occur, you should be able to name it. I asked you to (twice before, three times now). If you can't name it, then your assertion that it exists is unsupported, and that means you can't legitimately use it to support your position.

Answer (score 4):

> "final solution" is a reference to the bad context and should not be used

If you see "final solution" as a reference to the bad context is subject of one's own interpretation but I would dare to say it is an inappropriate association.

Stack Overflow is a community to seek, find and give help with problems related to programming.

Essentially, problems need *solutions* to be solved.

A "final solution" is IMHO a solution, which "*finally solves*" the issue and/or answers the question asked (f.e. after some feedback in the comments to the said answer and the specific answer got improved to *finally* solve the issue). That's all.

The term "final solution" or any other terms used regarding to the topics discussed at Stack Overflow should not be connected with *any* specific meaning beside what's on-topic here.

Following to answer:

> Can the expression “final solution” be used on the site?

Yes, of course. Do not interpret things in something, which are completely off any sense and context.

> edits of "final solution" wording is a reference to the bad context and should not be done

However, edits are there to improve a post. If a user feels to improve your post in this way by cleaning out the bad context someone might associate with any wording inside of the post then this is completely fine as well.

But "final solution" isn't ultimately connected to the bad context in the first place and not each and every answer which contains "final solution" should now be edited to shape. That's just a specific case. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can, if you are referring the solution to the software development problem. And even if it isn't, I bet you could have used it. The term itself isn't bad, what is bad is when you use it to denoting that you want to carry the negative actions that the term connotative.

Counterexample for our US friends: [Germany has a Nazi museum since 2015](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/germany-just-opened-nazi-museum-180955154/). Yes, an entire museum dedicated to explain that part of German history. Not to celebrate it, nor commemorate it, but to document it. It's my opinion that Germany is preventing the adage of "those that cannot learn from history are condemned to repeat it". If the Germans can do that, I bet the rest of the world can do that too. (BTW, they also have [several mausoleums remembering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Holocaust_memorials_and_museums#Germany) the victims)

Comment: This would be relevant if the OP's use of "final solution" was an intentional reminder or record of historical events; and that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @khelwood that's what the editor through too. This is the counterargument to that idea.

Comment: I'm saying that your counterexample, which is a museum in Germany, is not analogous to this situation because it's an intentional reminder, done for a particular purpose, not an accidental one. If someone set up a museum with *accidental* Nazi content, it would probably need to be revised.

Comment: @khelwood again, accidental or not has no relevance. That's the point of the example: even when intentional context is more relevant.

Answer (score -7):

If it were my post, I would roll this edit back purely as a matter of principle.

SO has become inundated with a push toward critical race theory philosophy (or whatever name you want to apply to the modern social movement). The most  prominent example of this in action would be the removal of Monica as a moderator, but it has shown up in many other ways. This ideology is destructive because it drives people to judge others according to race, gender, and other classes rather than as individuals. (It quite literally explicitly rejects the idea that you are uniquely defined as an individual with your own thoughts, choices, and actions rather than as merely a member of particular classes.) This is the ideology that has produced notions such as "white privilege," "systemic racism" (which does not comprise of actual racist acts), and "social justice" (which would be more descriptively named "group justice" or "class justice" and has little to do with historical and typical meanings of "justice"). This sort of edit constitutes an embrace of the concept of "microaggressions," which is an effort to convince people to constantly interpret virtually everything they do or experience as an attack based on classes rather than in the spirit in which it was intended. The result of such thinking is that people cannot engage in constructive interactions.

So while this edit would not, in isolation, be a problem, I oppose it because it is one small expression of a much larger destructive trend.

Comment: "Quite literally explicitly"? What does that mean?

Comment: @10Rep It's a combination of expressing shock that it embraces such a claim and emphasizing the fact that it's a core principle, as opposed to some side implication of its principles.

Comment: Well, one thing, StackOverflow actually don't promote such edits. Even in tour and COC, they specifically state, "Always assume good faith". So just as a side note, StackOverflow doesn't embrace nor promote such edits.

Comment: @10Rep The CoC means absolutely nothing when it comes to promoting their ideas on race, gender, and other classes or silencing ideas they oppose. Monica's treatment makes that blatantly obvious. I've experienced violations by *employees* over it.

Comment: I was not here when all that happened, but I would like to say that most users abide by the COC. And site moderators, not the employees , but the moderators whom we elect, enforce this policy. In fact, I have seen certain site moderators remind other users about it.

Comment: @10Rep The trail is still there. You can go to meta.stackexchange and search for "Firing Community Managers". There's multiple threads and they're all a long read.

Comment: @10Rep Some moderators are dutiful about upholding the values that underpinned the old "Be Nice" policy. Several employees are not when it comes to people who disagree with their sociopolitical beliefs.