# Should we edit all "Final Solution" expression usages on the site?

Tags: discussion, edits, word-filter

Based on [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401489/can-the-expression-final-solution-be-used-on-the-site) results, I think it is obvious that community is mostly against these words on the site, because they can hurt someone.

Currently I see the [19 usages of this expression on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22final%20solution%22). And [10k+ on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22final%20solution%22).

Should I start editing them?

Should we propose a new word filter for this phrase to help people with different cultural context to avoid hurting somebody accidentally?

Comment: I think the better question would be to ask if the community agrees that the expression is gratuitous, offensive and/or hurtful. This is the first time I have ever seen this expression being censored, and I am 54 years old.

Comment: This is what happens when context is overapplied. https://old.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/h8w36t/github_will_no_longer_use_the_term_master_as/fuuf948/

Comment: *"is mostly against these words on the site, because they can hurt someone."* - I fail to see how you came to that conclusion, the most upvoted answer says assume good faith and don't actively make these edits?

Comment: @Nick situation has dramatically changed after this question

Comment: Also, literally any word can hurt someone if it's applied properly. This is why assuming good faith and not overreacting to stuff like this is important, especially since there's a whole bunch of cultures among users

Comment: @astef It still applies though, you can't assume consensus and claim it obvious within _an hour and a half_. That's not nearly enough time to decide the community is "mostly" against something. The post has only been seen by 125 people!, and that's _after_ the additional time since this question was posted

Comment: @Nick Sure, I was overreacting a bit, I agree. And I'm glad it is clear for everybody now

Comment: I think Jon Skeet said it well in [a comment thread on the original post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401489/can-the-expression-final-solution-be-used-on-the-site#comment798314_401492): "Sure, up to a point - but for me, "editing a post" is definitely within that point. Suggesting a site-wide search and replace would be beyond that point, IMO - but I really think this edit is a positive contribution to the site."

Comment: @HereticMonkey: This question is not about a single edit. This question is about editing well over ___10k___ posts.

Comment: @Cerbrus Read that quote again. "Suggesting a site-wide search and replace would be beyond that point, IMO" The whole reason I posted it was to draw attention to Jon's statement that doing a site-wide search and replace would be a step too far.

Comment: Ah yea, You're right. It seems I read over the "beyond", there...

Comment: There is a [power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) in place in terms of view rate (probably mostly from search engines hits) that you can use to your advantage: Editing 0.1% (that is 10) of those 10,000 may accomplish 90% of the impact (in terms of page views). (It is statistical, though - any given post could go viral at any time on social media.) Or in other words, there isn't any need to be a completionist.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## No.

Aside from the fact that the discussion on the linked post is far from over, you wouldn't be helping anyone with those edits.

You'd just be drawing more and more (negative) attention to a certain combination of words that were taken ***completely out of context***.

I also think it's a horrible idea to plainly blacklist a combination of words like that. That's just asking for false positives.

Comment: Discussion is far from over indeed. I think this question changed the balance.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't really target posts based on some single phrase. That would bump them all en masse which would interfere with our ability to see when posters have updated their questions with new information.

Editing 10K+ posts and fixing every issue in them isn't going to be feasible anyway. New ones will be created almost as you fix old ones.

If there are a small number of posts that need fixing for some issue or other then make sure you fix every issue in each post that you edit.

If you convinced Stack Overflow's staff that this was an issue, they could fix all the posts without bumping them. There's a pretty high bar for them to take such an action and I suspect this issue does not rise above that bar.

Comment: What's your thoughts about the new filter then? Would you vote for it to be introduced to avoid creating new posts with these words?

Comment: @astef this is why there is a rule of asking only one question at a time, people have to pick and choose what they feel comfortable responding to and you are left wondering about that which is left unspoken :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, **you** could do that

There is not particular requirement how one selects posts to edit. If you feel that particular phrase need to be fixed across the site you are welcome to go through the posts one-by-one and *fix all and every problem* with each individual post.

While large scale editing is frowned upon doing it properly will naturally limit your edits to somewhat small number of edits a day. I would estimate that 4-5 hours a day should get you probably 50 posts updated which I feel acceptable.

Note that "final solution", "ultimate solution", "the best solution", "the most optimal solution" and variations of that are generally not acceptable in a question on SO due to being too broad (whether any of those have historical or political meaning is somewhat secondary) - make sure to add concrete criteria for each question that aligns with existing answers (if any).

**What you should not do** is just go though all those posts and just bulk-replace one phrase with another.