# What makes this question about CSS selectors not focused enough?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

I've slightly modified this question (([How can I disable a whole CSS stylesheet on a specific list of domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64168363/5825294))) but I don't think it makes a difference.

What makes that question unfocused, and is it possible to edit it so it can be reopened?

Comment: 1. what are you using to apply the stylesheets in the first place? What browser or browsers do you want this to work on?

Comment: You're asking if there's a piece of CSS that will make everything better for every site on the internet. Or something. Apparently I have to click some links to find out what you're talking about, and that's not something I'm going to do. If the question can't be answered with code and text in the question itself I'm gone. I would've just downvoted; but apparently some people voted to close.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, do you like it a bit more or a bit less, now?

Comment: @HereticMonkey While the links might help explain a bit of background, they aren't necessary to understand the question, which is "if CSS offers a way to not apply a sequence of rulesets (in my case it'd be the whole stylesheet) on some domains.", which is quite reasonably focused and on-topic IMO. Answer might be "In pure CSS, no". (It may well be a duplicate, I'm a bit surprised I didn't see another question about this after looking through a couple pages searching)

Comment: The original formulation of the question was a single sentence "The thing is, I'm using solarized-everything-css to get a dark theme on qutebrowser, but it seems the result on some website is unsatisfactory, so I'd like to add each problematic site to a sort of blacklist for which the CSS stylesheet is not applied." Which didn't didn't say anything about "not applying a sequence of rulesets" and which was the revision that was closed @CertainPerformance. The most recent revision is vastly improved and I voted to reopen. I don't know that there is a way of doing it either, but that's a valid A.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350880/what-is-stack-exchanges-official-stance-on-words-such-as-black-list-white-l/352702#352702         https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401489/can-the-expression-final-solution-be-used-on-the-site/401543#401543

Answer (score -1):

From the comments, it looks like you need to explain that the browser you're using, qutebrowser, allows you to set a CSS file that applies those styles to every web site you visit but doesn't allow you to set it per page/domain.

That you're trying to see if there's a CSS solution to this is clear.

Comment: I don't agree. Telling about qutebrowser is just more info. My question is simple: is there a CSS way of excluding a webpage from being applied a ruleset? If there's a way, that's independent of the browser. However, maybe changing the question as you suggest will make it more appealing. Let's see.

Comment: @Enrico The information you added about qutebrowser not supporting per-domain styles is quite useful/relevant. Without information about your specific environment, we might just suggest "use Chrome/Firefox and get Stylus". Since we know you want to use qutebrowser, and now we know it doesn't support the 'specific subdomain' subfeature within the 'custom user style' feature, we can answer more completely.

Comment: Fair enough, @TylerH.